# Salesforce DEV - TEST - Package Enviroments

Tags: managed-package, app-development, developer-edition

I am trying to figure out how to set up this four enviroments on Salesforce

I am trying to avoid using ANT Migration Tool.

My Production Environent is a Developer Edition in which I am going to create a Managed Package, so I am unable to passing the application through enviroments in a unmanaged package.

What are the best practices ? Jenkins ?

[image]

Comment: what is a problem with ant? Personally I setup pipeline based on Jenkins/Grunt/Ant/Git to do deployment based on corresponding branches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/12/salesforce-dx-source-driven-development.html). Fortunately, there's a [pilot](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/salesforce-dx-pilot.html) going on right now so you can get front-row seats for how this is going to work. We're still a few months away from GA, but it will be ideal for the scenario that you envision: developing a managed package without the need for Ant. If you can't wait, the current process would be to use Ant. If you do choose to use Jenkins, it automates deployments, but still requires Ant scripts. However, using a CI is recommended, because it's far less error prone than using Deploy to Server that you'll find in MavensMate or the current Force.com IDE.

Comment: @Oleksiy Thanks for the edit. That does make more sense.

Comment: We cannot wait for DX to be GA, it will be such a modernization of the development experience on Salesforce. Our current flow leverages Git and Jenkins and is a bit of work to maintain, but could give you the flow you want above. The way we work it is that we have specific branches in Git for each of our environments. Changes to and pull requests against these different branches trigger test runs and deployments via ANT in Jenkins to move code to the next step until it ends up in the packaging org. Uploading beta/released packages is still a manual step.

Answer (score 1):

I think what I was looking is the "Deploy to Server" tool of Mavensmate.

[image]

Comment: Force.com IDE also has this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Since DX will take time until GA, we settled for Jason Laantz's/Salesforce Foundation's [CumulusCI](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/CumulusCI) - running on python.

We run CumulusCI with [CircleCI](https://circleci.com) currently - but there's also [MrBelvedereCI](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/mrbelvedereci) by the same peeps.

So far I am very, very happy with CumulusCI.